# jQuery to Transition Between on Page Anchors/ID Pairs

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I've got a big page with a bunch of divs all the same size, all uniquely ID'ed. Originally, I was using the jQuery ScrollTo/LocalScroll to move between the different anchors, but the client wants a more subtle transition, like a fade in/fade out. Is such a thing possible with jQuery?

Simplified code of my page is below at jsFiddle.net:

http://jsfiddle.net/Keefer/PWzf2/6/

Click the bottom right hand link to popup the navigation. Basically, I want to transition between the different divs with some sort of fading. Is that possible with .animate or some jQuery plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the .[fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and .[fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) commands, does this fit your requirements?

Comment: I don't think so. Looking for for a crossfade, type thing if it's possible.

Comment: You should be able to use these methods with it if you do them fast and css it so they are over top of one another.  I'm unsure what you mean by crossfade, I'm assuming you mean fade from one to another without a period with nothing visible.

Comment: So I gave it a try and it works well enough. Only problem is it seems to disable the back button. I just added this to my document ready function: ``$('.question a, #presentationNav a').click(function() {
        $("#presentation").css("display", "none");
        $("#presentation").fadeIn(2000);
    });``

Comment: It disables your back button?  I've never heard of that before, but some Googling reveals a couple of other people having the same issue with the fadeIn command.  Could you edit your original post with that code snippet for future Googlers, and mark the question as answered if you are happy with the result?